# How to cancel an iBatis prepared statement?

Tags: ibatis, aspectj

I need a solution for cancelling a long-running select statement. 
I'm using Spring 3.0.2, iBatis 2.3.0 and Oracle 10g.
I managed to get it to work with plain JDBC, but because the select is generated dynamically through an advanced search screen, I really need to use iBatis.

The iBatis internal class responsible for the creation/retrieval from cache of prepared statements is **com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor**. The internal method called for every call of **queryForList()/queryForObject()** is SqlExecutor's

`public void executeQuery(RequestScope request, Connection conn, String sql, Object[] parameters, int skipResults, int maxResults, RowHandlerCallback callback) throws SQLException`
method.

Due to performance reasons, iBatis creates a new prepared statement only if one does not already exist for the given select statement.
The prepared statements are stored/cached in a HashMap where the sql string is the key and the prepared statement is the value.

After trying different other solutions with no success, I think it might be possible to work with AOP (**AspectJ**) to try to pointcut the SqlExecutor.executeQuery() method and somehow store on the HTTP session the iBatis cache map and sql string.

When the user will try to cancel the long-running query, a check will be made from another thread to see if a prepared statement already exists in the iBatis cache map for the given sql string, previously stored on the HTTP session through AOP.
If one does exist, a Statement.cancel() call will be issued.
I don't see why a solution like this might interfere with the iBatis internal mechanisms since if the prepared statement will be canceled, an SqlException will be thrown (**ORA-01013 user requested cancel of current operation**) and Ibatis will properly handle that as any other generated SqlException.

Using **Spring AOP** is not an option because it only allows you to pointcut methods declared in objects managed by the Spring container. I cannot declare SqlExecutor as a Spring bean, because it is created and managed internally by iBatis.

Haven't yet tried the above solution with AspectJ since I'm not quite familiar with the AspectJ framework.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach for this, but I didn't find another solution to cancel a prepared statement created by iBatis, as iBatis doesn't seem to offer any support for this (have also checked myBatis).

Comment: I have no idea about iBatis or how this should be done properly. It would be a nice challenge for me from the AspectJ perspective, though. So if you would please prepare a little [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for me to clone from GitHub including a Maven build and a long-running statement against some in-memory DB or so, I will see what I can do for you. BTW, is it fine for you to use compile-time weaving in order to create an aspect-enhanced iBatis library to use later in production or would you prefer LTW (load-time weaving)?

Comment: @kriegaex This question is close to 7 years old, I doubt the OP will have any use of it in case anyone answers. Maybe the OP should delete the question as it doesn't seem like one that would help anyone else.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice. It popped up in my AspectJ RSS feed just now because for whatever reason the question was edited 5 hours go. Quite funny, isn't it? Thanks for the hint, Nándor. BTW, it seems he did not get an answer on the [MyBatis mailing list](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Canceling-Statements-td2549512.html) either.

Comment: @kriegaex Yes, I know, someone did a cosmetic edit and it popped up in my tag feed too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting a reference to the connection which is running the statement, and invalidating the connection?

Answer (score 0):

I know, the question is old, but maybe someone will find that useful.

You may use the plugin mechanism provided by iBatis. Here is a working example, which is a bit complex though. It doesn't require any specific library or environment, just iBatis/myBatis (version 3.x is used here).

We first start by defining a `Cancelable` interface:

```
public interface Cancelable {
    void cancel();
}
```

Then we have a handler that stores the last `java.sql.Statement` and cancel it by request:

```
class CancelHandler implements Cancelable {

    Statement lastStatement;

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        if (lastStatement != null) {
            try {
                lastStatement.cancel();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // cancel failed or not supported (ignore)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To remember the last statement we need to wrap the `org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler`:

```
public class StatementHandlerWrapper implements StatementHandler {

    private final StatementHandler wrapped;

    private static final ThreadLocal<CancelHandler> CANCEL_HANDLER = ThreadLocal.withInitial(CancelHandler::new);

    public static Cancelable getQueryCancelHandler() {
        return CANCEL_HANDLER.get();
    }

    public StatementHandlerWrapper(StatementHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public List query(Statement statement, ResultHandler resultHandler) throws SQLException {
        CancelHandler cancelHandler = CANCEL_HANDLER.get();
        try {
            cancelHandler.lastStatement = statement;
            return wrapped.query(statement, resultHandler);
        } finally {
            cancelHandler.lastStatement = null;
        }
    }

    // implement all other methods by just delegating to the wrapped handler
}
```

The last step is to create your plugin:

```
public class StatementHandlerInterceptor implements org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        return invocation.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public Object plugin(Object target) {
        if (target instanceof StatementHandler) {
            return new StatementHandlerWrapper((StatementHandler) target);
        }
        return target;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {}
}
```

And register it in your `mapping.xml` where you define all your iBatis mappings:

```
<configuration>
  <plugins>
    <plugin interceptor="com.example.StatementHandlerInterceptor" />
  </plugins>
  <mappers>
    <!-- all your mappers go here -->
  </mappers>
<configuration>
```

To use this little framework, we could create a `java.util.concurrent.Callable`:

```
public class QueryTask implements Callable<List<?>>, Cancelable {

    private Cancelable cancelHandler;

    @Override
    public List<?> call() throws Exception {
        cancelHandler = StatementHandlerWrapper.getQueryCancelHandler();

        // execute your query here and return the result
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        if (cancelHandler != null) {
            cancelHandler.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

And the main thread could look like this:

```
QueryTask queryTask = new QueryTask();
Future<List<?>> futureResult = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(queryTask);
// either cancel or get the result
queryTask.cancel();
List<?> result = futureResult.get();
```

If you find a simpler solution, please write a comment.